# How to access common dll instance across nodejs processes in electron?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, electron, child-process, node-ffi

I am working on an electron application where I faced issues of blocking of renderer process due to main process accessing operations in Dll (using node-ffi) created from Golang application.
These DLL methods are called in a sequence and some methods of DLL has to be executed in order for the other methods to work.

To make these executions called in main process not block the renderer, I have used "electron-remote" (https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-remote) which can create separate processes (using requireTaskPool). So, in main process I instantiate the node-ffi object from the DLL and execute certain methods from the ffi object.
But in the new processes created using task pool of electron-remote, the DLL'd ffi is a new instance. Also, if we pass DLL object as an argument to new process created using electron-remote, we have an empty DLL (no object properties).

I am a newbie to concurrent processing in nodejs. Is there any way we can get to use the same instance of the ffi object created from dll in the main process of the electron application in other processes forked using child process or electron-remote?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way we can get to use the same instance of the ffi object created from dll in the main process of the electron application in other processes forked using child process or electron-remote

There is no such way. Since it's completely different process, there is no way to make singleton instance shared among different processes. Also it's expected to pass DLL object to new process becomes empty, as electron's IPC only allows serializable object to be passed.

In short, way for using one ffi object across process is not trying to share ffi object, but only one process behaves as task runner and other process invokes request / response via IPC.

Comment: Making one process as task runner and other one process the request and response via IPC works when main process can be freed by delegating work to background process. But imagine a case where we need to run multiple background processes (for parallel or concurrency) by freeing the main process. Here creating a new process would create a new ffi object but what we really need is the same instance of ffi object.

Comment: I am aware of what you want, but simply that is not possible. You literally can't share same instance of ffi object across process - you need to design your application with those limitation.